# Error trying to save child object with Entity Framework in a 1:1 relation (c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Entity Framework 6 with SQL Server 2016, I have a problem when I try to save a child object.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Agregar(Pacientes oPaciente)
{
    if (oPaciente.Nombre != null)
    {
        using (var oModel = new pamidbEntities())
        {
            var o_new_pac = new Pacientes();
            o_new_pac.Apellido = oPaciente.Apellido;
            o_new_pac.Nombre = oPaciente.Nombre;
            o_new_pac.DNI = oPaciente.DNI;
            o_new_pac.NroAfiliado = oPaciente.NroAfiliado;
            o_new_pac.Sexo = oPaciente.Sexo;
            o_new_pac.Correo = oPaciente.Correo;
            o_new_pac.FechaNacimiento = oPaciente.FechaNacimiento;
            o_new_pac.Descripcion = oPaciente.Descripcion;

            oModel.Pacientes.Add(o_new_pac);
            oModel.SaveChanges();

            o_new_pac.Anannesis = oPaciente.Anannesis;
            oModel.Anannesis.Add(o_new_pac.Anannesis);
            oModel.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pacientes");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

The first object `o_new_pac`, it is saved ok, but I get this error when try to save `o_new_pac.Anannesis`:

> InnerException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'."
>
> System.Exception> {System.InvalidOperationException}

Between these two objects I have a 1:1 relation.

[image]

The way it is related is the following:

[image]

[image]

I don't know if I'm saving the object incorrectly or my be data base design is wrong.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605152/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c looks similar to your issue.

Comment: I did not know those fields were about to be removed, and thanks for the tips. 
The url help me a lot, yes it´s a similar to my issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could  solve the problem. In the chield Anannesis, it had the PK as identity auto-generated, how they say in link [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column error on 1-to-1 relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605152/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c), the problem is when entity framework try to save the chield and put an Id.

My unique solution was take out the PK as identity.