# Cannot save record to database with 1 : 1 mapping using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my code, I have 2 "tables" which have a 1 to 1 or 1 to 0 mapping. A `person` table and a `passport` table (I'm showing code that replicates my issue, so please forgive how contrived these examples are). This means a person may not have a passport, but a passport must have a person associated.

The problem I have is when I save, I get the following error message

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.

I must admit, I don't actually really understand the issue here! Yes I can read the words but I don't know why it is struggling with `Id` column!

This is what I have

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PassportId {get;set;}

    public virtual Passport Passport {get;set;}
}

[Table("Passport")]
public partial class Passport 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PassportDetail { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Entities (DataContext) I have

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()              //create for person
            .HasOptional(a => a.Passport)      //a person has optional passport
            .WithRequired(s => s.Person);      //a passport requires a person
}
```

Saving to the database should have been simple...

```
var p = new Person();
p.Passport = new Passport()
        {
              PassportDetail = "test"
        };
dataContext.Person.Add(p);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I am told off for the reason above.

What have I done wrong?

Posts like [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384659/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c) seem to be very complex and about poorly defined tables where as I hope (famous last words) my situation is simple and I've avoided this)

The accepted answer in [A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column error on 1-to-1 relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605152/a-dependent-property-in-a-referentialconstraint-is-mapped-to-a-store-generated-c) seems shows what do!

The fix is update to

```
[Table("Passport")]
public partial class Passport 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]  //changed here
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
….
```

However, if I do that, then when I save to my database, I'm being told off for inserting duplicates :(

Comment: First clarify one thing please! One person will have one or zero passport, isn't ?

Comment: Correct @TanvirArjel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality `one-to-one` relationship is not possible in `sql server`. It can be `one-to-zero-or-one` relationship. In your case one `Person` will have one or zero `Passport`, so can simply the relationship as follows where `Person` in the principal entity and `Passport` is the dependent entity.

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public PersonName {get;set;}

    public virtual Passport Passport {get;set;}
}

[Table("Passport")]
public partial class Passport 
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }  //<-- here `PersonId` the is both the Primary key and foreign key

    public string PassportDetail { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Note: In this set up you don't need any `Fluent API` configuration.

And during insert:

```
var person = new Person()
{
    PersonName = "Test"
}

Passport passport = new Passport()
{
      PersonId = person.Id,
      PassportDetail = "test"
};

dataContext.Persons.Add(person);
dataContext.Passports.Add(passport);
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for this... I'm panicing a little bit because I've never created a table which doesn't have an ID :(

Comment: Haha! Actually here `PersonId` is  the `Id` and `ForeignKey`  at the same time.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Already I have been cleared of regarding this from the OP. He said that he will have one-to-zero or one passport. Please read the comment below the question. If One Person has more than one passport then it will be one-to-many relationship which the questioner don't want.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu You may have different opinion but if you want one-to-one-or-zero relationship than this is the best approach. You can check EF/EF core official documentation.

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu here is the EF framework official documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu Please read official documentation provided by EF team please!

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu By the way. I respect your different opinion and you also have right to down vote anything if you don't like.  Take care. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188467/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-andrei-dragotoniu).

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I strongly disagree. What Tanvir is proposing is called [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), is the default and preferred design for 1 to 0..1 relationships in both EF6 and EF Core. Also in EF6 it's the only fully supported one-to-one mapping - FK mapping is possible, but with limitations. Shortly, this is the best db design for such relationship.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions See the **Ivan Stoev** comment here. `Ivan Stoev` is one of the most expert person in `Stack Overflow` community who has very in depth knowledge in Both `EF` and `EF Core`.

Comment: @TanvirArjel: StackOverflow usually detects this sort of "serial down-voting" and then reverses it in 1-2 days, however you may want to also notify a moderator through a flag about these actions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks a lot! I shall wait for the reversing! If not then will flag.

Comment: @TanvirArjel: Andrei Dragotoniu shows no negative rep on his profile today, suggesting that he did not down-vote your answers. He may have a dup profile, but no way for us mortals to know. Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: Down voted repo does not show on down voter profile. This is stack overflow privacy.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  By the way thanks for your heartfelt concern.

Comment: His comments remain here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188467/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-andrei-dragotoniu which I have screen shots of

Answer (score 4):

I think the quick fix you found its not the proper way to deal with EF Code first ideolegy, in order to have a one-to-one relationship you have to match each table with the other table primary key , in your case its an int Id , but for the person you want this option to be optional so you mark it as nullable and EF will generate the right scripts to allow a creation of a Person without a Passport or with and a Passport is only allowed to be created if there is an association with a person

```
[Table("Person")]
public partial class Person
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? PassportId {get;set;}

    public virtual Passport Passport {get;set;}
}

[Table("Passport")]
public partial class Passport 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PassportDetail { get; set; }

    public int PersonId {get;set;}

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```